# Export Data not working on Parse

Tags: parse-platform, export

I'm currently using Parse for one of my app and I'd like to export all my data. I know there a way to do this, so I went in "Settings" > "Export Data" > Export Data button. I have done that several times, but I never received an email with the .zip file. The success message appears "Your app was exported successfully!". I have rebooted my computer, and I have tried several times since yesterday. The email in my account if 100% correct. What am I doing wrong?

Bonus: If you know a way to export in JSON, you'll make my day

Comment: I have exact same problem, I was wondering if my parse account was using an old email account, but so far I have not found any way to confirm what email my Parse account is linked to.

Comment: Seems to be an internal glitch. I have another account with a different email, and I can export whenever I want with it. Still cannot with the first account. Shame on you, Parse!

Comment: I was able to confirm my email account (there is a little widget in account settings that is almost hidden), but still, no exports to my account. No further help from support

Answer (score 1):

You can now change emails on Parse. I did that and exported the data and it worked.